# Why are PRWeb Referrals not showing up?

Tags: google-analytics

I created a [PRWeb Release](http://www.prweb.com/releases/embeddedanalytics/embeddedcharts/prweb9466323.htm).  When I check Google Analytics I don't find any referrals from the PRWeb link itself (even though my server logs show many visits).  It does detect the referrals from news agencies that have picked up the release ([Example](http://www.mysanantonio.com/business/press-releases/article/EmbeddedAnalytics-Takes-the-Burden-out-of-Logging-3527045.php)).

Why aren't the PRWeb links being picked up by GA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely because nobody came first to your site from the links on PRWeb site but from agencies that have picked up the release.
(you can check your server logs to verify if people coming from PRWeb do not come from another source just before)

Comment: I see many instances of referring links from the original PRWeb page. sorry - should have specified that originally.  Updated question to reflect that.

Comment: Response update to. Referrals doesn't update cookie within the same session.

Comment: Yep - you are right.  The references in the log I saw were triggered by elements in the release itself (you can include an iframe pointing back to your site).  I misconstrued these for actual visits.  Bummer - thought this PRWeb would be way more effective :(